# How do I sample a smaller data set from a very large dataset?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have a very large dataset with dimension given by  ( 203,000 x 150), with some of the columns (attributes) have a very large number of missing values, denoted by NA. I need to sample a smaller dataset from this so that I can run tests on my computer. 
Any suggestions on how to best do this ? 
I am very new to this area and therefor don't have much expertise.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to do?  "Run tests" is pretty non specific.  Also 203000 x 150 is not "very large" for today's computers.

Comment: Is this a question about theory of sampling (in which case it belongs at stats.SE site), or about implementation in the existing software (in which case you need to indicate the packages available to you... and it would then still belong to stackoverflow site)?

Comment: No. I am just looking for ways to get a smaller dataset from this one.

Comment: @deinst.. yes, i don't have access to high-end computers at this moment. My laptop isn't capable of handling this data unfortunately.